# Serenity Template Partial view is not rendering data

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using serenity template and editing right navigation panel(div) where I want to show my notification queue. For PUC purpose I am sending dummy data from controller to partial view (I am hitting controller action from Postman and accepting that data to be reflected in my Partial view)

Here is my code

## Partial View

## --RightNavigation.cshtml--

```
@model ESignature.Model.Notifications

<input type="text">@Model.Message</input>
```

========================================

ControllerActionMathod

```
[HttpPost, AllowAnonymous]     
    public ActionResult CallPost()
    {
       Notifications notification = new Notifications();
       notification.Message = "And i am iron man!!";                    
       return PartialView(MVC.Views.Shared.RightNavigation, notification);
    }
```

========================================

when I debug I received data in variable but it is not reflecting on UI

Comment: So ```@Model.Message``` has value but the element doesn't show on screen? Have you checked if the element is hidden? by css or something?

Comment: yes. Element is showing on UI but value is no showing

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see if the value is actually there? Have you checked if it's there in chrome devtools?

Comment: Can provider how you render this partial view?  Ajax? Html.Action?

Comment: I inspect the value in razor and it is showing "And i am iron man!!" correct value.

Comment: <input type="text" bgcolor="yellow">Ye ho gaya kaam</input> this is returning from Postman

Comment: @{Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Views.Shared.RightNavigation, new ESignature.Model.Notifications()); }

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@model ESignature.Model.Notifications

<input type="text" value="@Model.Message"/>
```

and controller action

```
 [HttpPost, AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult CallPost()
    {
        Notifications notification = new Notifications();
        notification.Message = "And i am iron man!!";
        return PartialView("RightNavigation", notification);
    }
```